# 95 Integra: Broken Nipple to hose

Tags: hose

While wrenching on the starter, my hand struck a small hose and it broke the nipple of (what I think is) the Evaporator Purge Control Diaphragm (EPCD):

[image]

I am investigating alternatives to replacing the EPCD by bridging the EPCD to the hose.  I bought an array of off the shelf parts to attemp to bridge the EPCD -> hose.

## QUESTION

Is there a clever technique to overcome the bridging problem?  Thank you

Context of closeup:

[image]

Comment: They couldn't have put that in a better spot, eh? I've only ever fixed something like this using superglue ... not the best solution, but better than buying a new canister (or even finding a used one).

Answer (score 3):

That cap is the Purge control.  The cap will come off if you are super careful, it just snaps on. There will be a diaphragm and spring under the cap. I fix broken nipples with small hose connectors. I choose one that is smaller than the hole in the cap. Drill out the old nipple to the size into which the hose connector can be pushed in. Add a little glue and it works OK. If the connector you choose has a barb on it this can be used as a way to keep the new nipple from pulling out or it can be filed off if needed.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan: Is there a good place to find small hose connectors?  Is this a problem if drive the car for a few short trips in order to repair this or am I introducing a serious damage?

Comment: I get them at an auto parts store.  Before driving plug the vacuum hose to avoid a leak.

Answer (score 2):

@Paulster2 Superglue is brilliant stuff (cyano-acrylate glue), but find a thin-wall tube to slide inside the two broken parts, which will add strength to the repair. Or, if the rubber tube is still flexible, then a tube that slides over the broken part could also work.

Comment: how does the glue cope with heat in engine bay, oils, and water splashes from below?

Comment: Works fine for what I have used it for, you may want to ask Paulster2 for his experiences ... but the instructions didn't preclude heat oil water, especially as it was said to be suitable for porcelain - however, before you use the glue you purchase : read the instructions and data provided completely.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar mishap on my Subaru and broke the purge solenoid nipple while wrenching on the car. I went on ebay and found a replacement solenoid very cheap. I think it was around $30 used. The good news in this situation is that you can drive your car while you are missing the valve. You will get a check engine light because the engine will have to compensate for the loss of fuel vapor. The loss of vapor is so minimal I really did not notice any fuel loss. I ended up buying new silicone tubing and a few plastic tube joiners at Advance Auto that I needed. I installed the part 4 or 5 days later.